# How to perform table calculation when blend data using conditional string dimensions

Tags: aggregate-functions, tableau-api, calculated-field

A common use case for my analysis is blend a secondary data source then do a table calculation with various independent measures (thus I cannot apply filters). The condition is offer status = hired, but offer status can contain my different response types.

```
IF
ATTR([Offer Status]) = "Hired"
Then AVG([Comp_File].[Cash PTM])
Else [Null] END
```

Since I am blending the datasource, the values must be aggregated.

Here's a link to the notebook: https://community.tableau.com/message/671932?et=watches.email.thread#671932

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Do you want a calculation that takes multiple variations of the possible content of the [offer status] field by using ELSE?

Comment: In English, I want it to query by row for anyone who has a status of hired, then return their PTM. Next, I want to render the results along a new dimension, say Business Unit with an average value. 

The insight would be for a given BU, their average PTM is this compared to another BU.

Comment: Okay, so your half way there - sounds like you need to create a second calculated field to benchmark the PTM against an average - are you able to share a sample workbook?

Comment: @BenP, I updated my original post with a link to the workbook.

Comment: Please attach a .twbx packaged workbook that has your data embedded into it, so that we can see it.

Comment: @BenP, I'm not able to attach on this post. I updated my original post with a link to the twbx package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. I attended a 'Tableau Doctor' session at the Tableau Conference, and the expert confirmed this functionality is not possible on a blend due to the order of operations, with blending happening last on Tableau's processing logic/order of operations.

To solve, use a left join.